# Is it possible to post code snippet with Botkit to Slack

Tags: node.js, slack, botkit

I'd like to know is it possible to post a message with attachment, similar like I can add using Slack' action **Code or text snippet**, as the reply from my bot. Should I use *bot.reply* or maybe some other method?

Comment: Text snippets are not message attachments, but uploaded files. You can upload files through the API, not sure though if botkit supports this. see [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload through the [files.upload API](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload), using the Botkit interface, like so:

```
slackBot.api.files.upload({
  file: fs.createReadStream('./codeForReview.js'),
  channels: '#general',
  initial_comment: 'Can you guys have a look at this please?',
  title: 'Updated code',
});
```